# When I take photo it is not shown on the imageView only in Galaxy s4

Tags: android

In my app I have to let the user take photo from camera / choose from gallery .
My code working fine on some device but when I run on Galaxy s4 and taking photo by camera the photo doesnt show on the imageView (choose from gallery -working fine)the problem is just when take photo by camera in Galaxy s4.
I scaled the picture before display it on the imageView.
Here is my code to take the picture:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

this is my code after take photo:

```
 if (requestCode == 1) 
                    { 
                        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                        File image_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                        for (File temp : f.listFiles())
                        {
                            if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg"))
                            {
                                f = temp;                           
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        try 
                        {
                            Bitmap bitmap;
                            //BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            //bitmap=decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());//Collapse image                         
                            //setImageOnBitmap(bitmap);//Set the image on the imageview



                            BitmapHandler b=new BitmapHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            bitmap=b.decodeFileAsPath(f.getAbsolutePath(),"camera");
                            setImageOnBitmap(bitmap);




                            String path = android.os.Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator
                                    + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                            f.delete();                       
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

this is my function to decode the file of the image:

```
  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{ // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) 
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) 
    {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: no. I check it , it just not display the image without error

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on S4, and this is what solved for me:

```
mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Hope this helps.